# Change a Rails application to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, production-environment

How can I change my Rails application to run in production mode? Is there a config file, environment.rb for example, to do that?

Comment: It seems that the second answer has lots more votes, would you be willing to give this a quick review and accept the second answer unless you have any issue with it. Will just help future visitors. Thx :)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

How to setup and run a Rails 4 app in Production mode (step-by-step) using Apache and Phusion Passenger:

Normally you would be able to enter your Rails project, `rails s`, and get a development version of your app at http://something.com:3000. Production mode is a little trickier to configure.

I've been messing around with this for a while, so I figured I'd write this up for the newbies (such as myself). There are a few little tweaks which are spread throughout the internet and figured this might be easier.

1. Refer to this guide for core setup of the server (CentOS 6, but it should apply to nearly all Linux flavors): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6
2. Make absolute certain that after Passenger is set up you've edited the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file to reflect your directory structure. **You want to point DocumentRoot to your Rails project /public folder** Anywhere in the `httpd.conf` file that has this sort of dir: `/var/www/html/your_application/public` needs to be updated or everything will get very frustrating. I cannot stress this enough.
3. Reboot the server (or Apache at the very least - `service httpd restart` )
4. Enter your Rails project folder `/var/www/html/your_application` and start the migration with `rake db:migrate`. Make certain that a database table exists, even if you plan on adding tables later (this is also part of step 1).
5. `RAILS_ENV=production rake secret` - this will create a secret_key that you can add to `config/secrets.yml` . You *can* copy/paste this into config/secrets.yml for the sake of getting things running, although I'd recommend you don't do this. Personally, I do this step to make sure everything else is working, then change it back and source it later.
6. `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`
7. `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` if you are serving static assets. This will push js, css, image files into the `/public` folder.
8. `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

At this point your app should be available at `http://something.com/whatever` instead of `:3000`. If not, `passenger-memory-stats` and see if there an entry like `908  469.7 MB  90.9 MB  Passenger RackApp: /var/www/html/projectname`

I've probably missed something heinous, but this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I feel like this answer should be migrated to stackoverflow documentation.

Comment: I would add that if you don't want to use a web content deliver like apache, you could add a RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1 next to the RAILS_ENV=production, that would mean that rails would serve every file so won't recommend this for a real-production state...

Answer (score 353):

This would now be

```
rails server -e production
```

Or, more compact

```
rails s -e production
```

It works for rails 3+ projects.

Comment: or the short version `rails s -e production`

Comment: What about cloud services like Heroku? How to run `server -e production` on them?

Comment: Cloud services usually have options to specify environment, but in them `production` is invariably the default.

Comment: `echo "export RAILS_ENV=production" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Much preferred answer, this one should make it to StackOverflow documentation.

Answer (score 62):

If you're running on [Passenger](http://modrails.com/), then the default is to run in production, in your apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName application_name.rails.local
  DocumentRoot "/Users/rails/application_name/public"
  RailsEnv production ## This is the default
</VirtualHost>
```

If you're just running a local server with mongrel or webrick, you can do:

```
./script/server -e production
```

or in bash:

```
RAILS_ENV=production ./script/server
```

actually overriding the RAILS_ENV constant in the enviornment.rb should probably be your last resort, as it's probably not going to stay set (see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915833/how-do-i-force-railsenvdevelopment-from-within-environment-rb-or-initializers/1916530#1916530) I gave on that)

Answer (score 54):

If [mipadi's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949229/change-an-rails-app-to-production/1949261#1949261) doesn't work, add this to config/environment.rb

```
# force Rails into production mode when                          
# you don't control web/app server and can't set it the proper way                  
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

Comment: What about cloud services like Heroku? May `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'` be applied on them too?

Comment: I edited this file long back and forgot.. thanks for reminding.. saved lot of time

Answer (score 19):

Change the environment variable `RAILS_ENV` to `production`.

Comment: where is the environment variable located?

Comment: may be located in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or simply `export RAILS_ENV=production"`

Answer (score 19):

```
$> export RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also pass the environment to script/server:

```
$ script/server -e production
```

Answer (score 12):

```
rails s -e production
```

This  will run the server with `RAILS_ENV` = `'production'`.

Apart from this you have to set the assets path in `production.rb`

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Without this your assets will not be loaded.

Comment: Sorry ... voted down when meant to upvote.  Made slight edit in order to correct error and upvote.

Answer (score 8):

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

OR

```
rails s -e production
```

By default environment is developement.

Answer (score 5):

As others have posted: `rails server -e production`

Or, my personal fave:  `RAILS_ENV=production` `rails s`

Answer (score 2):

In **Rails 3**

Adding **`Rails.env = ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new('production')`** into the application.rb and `rails s` will work same as `rails server -e production`

```
module BlacklistAdmin
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    Rails.env = ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new('production')

    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good way to run rails server in production environment by "rails server -e production", because then rails runs as a single-threaded application, and can only respond to one HTTP request at a time.

The best article about production environment for rails is [Production Environments - Rails 3](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596521424/production_id35801033.html)

Comment: Link rot... available on wayback machine though: [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20121022083645/http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596521424/production_id35801033.html)

Answer (score 1):

for default server : rails s -e production

for costum server port : rails s -p [port] -e production, eg. rails s -p 3002 -e production

Answer (score 1):

By default server runs on development environment: `$ rails s`

If you're running on production environment: `$ rails s -e production` or `$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have done below in your environment.rb file.

> ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

If you application runs in shared hosting environment or phushion passenger, you might need to need make changes in .httaccess (inside public folder) and set mode as production.