# Ruby, how to set GEM_PATH, for Rails project on hostmonster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am new to ruby and having a hard time setting up my gems. Could someone please help me understand how this path works in **environment.rb**

Some Background Info:

I have my rails app installed on hostmonster and I am trying to run SASS using SHELL. I have no local copy of my app. When I run the SASS command I get ***-bash: sass: command not found***. Which leads me to believe my gem path is wrong. The problem though is that  i don't really understand  how the path works.

**I am confused about this line in particular...**

```
home = File.expand_path("/home/#{ENV['USER']}")    
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "#{home}/ruby/gems:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8"
```

**NOTE:** This is the default path which was set when I installed my Rails app from the Cpanel.

**Some things I don't understand...**

1. What is the purpose of the semicolon?
2. For `#{home}` , am I suppose to replace that with my
   home directory?
3. Where would usr/lib64 come from? I don't see that directory. I am
   assuming I have to create it.

**ALSO:**
This is what hostmonster tells me to do (which I have done already)...

Using File Manager in your cPanel make a copy of the **.bashrc file** in
your root directory, name it **.bashrc.bak**. Now edit the .bashrc file
and add the following to the end of the file:

- export GEM_HOME=$HOME/ruby/gems
- export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
- export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ruby/gems/bin

When using a rails application, make sure you add the following to your ./config/environment.rb: 
ENV['GEM_PATH']'/path/to/your/home/ruby/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'

*I apologize if this is a "noobish" questions, I have never used Ruby so I am still learning how it all works. I have ruby, rails, and sass all installed. I can run my project in the browser. i just can't get my gems to work. Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well apparently the gems I was trying to use were not installed on my server. I thought I had installed them myself when I ran gem install sass. However this didn't work properly because Hostmonster had to give me permission to install gems.

**I found that out here...**

https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/221

**As for the path I had to do the following..**

```
home = File.expand_path("/home/#{ENV['MYCPANELUSERNAME']}")
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "#{home}/ruby/gems:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8"
```

So basically for the path all I had to do was change 'USER' to my cpanel username.

Also note this only works if my .htaccess is set to *"production"* instead of *"development*".

[Thread on production vs development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280318/running-a-rails-site-development-vs-production)

**And in addition to this I also had a problem with my .htaccess file.**

So I had to edit my .htacess file using vi editor. (might be different for other people)

**Make sure .htaccess had this content in it**

- Options -MultiViews
- PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
- RailsEnv production RackBaseURI / SetEnv GEM_HOME
- /home1/examplec/ruby/gems