# Unable to run sidekiq in production (Procfile + systemd)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, puma, foreman

I'm using *Foreman* and *Capistrano* to deploy my rails app. The `web` (i.e. *Puma*) process starts correctly, but I can't get my `worker` (i.e sidekiq) to run as a `production` environment.

I adapted the `app-worker-1.service` file generated in the *SystemD* export while tying to force the environment to be set correctly, without success:

```
[Unit]
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
User=deployment_user
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/app_name/current
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq -e production"

RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

SyslogIdentifier=%n

KillMode=process
```

I tried everything...I added `Logger.debug` statements that shows the `RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` are both incorrectly set to `development`.

Here is the error I get from the process journal:

```
I, [2015-09-19T13:56:14.813528 #31187]  INFO -- : Celluloid 0.17.1.2 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
D, [2015-09-19T13:56:16.765338 #31187] DEBUG -- : RACK_ENV=development
D, [2015-09-19T13:56:16.766057 #31187] DEBUG -- : RAILS_ENV=development
'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/var/www/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/var/www/app_name/releases/20150918131757/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657870/whenever-cron-job-in-rails-fails-with-production-database-is-not-configured-er

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

First I enabled debugging on SystemD:

```
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Then while looking a my services journal, my attention was drawn to a message that looked unrelated at first prompting to look at the service status itself...

```
capistrano@droplet2:/lib/systemd/system$ systemctl status app_name-worker-1.service
● alagarderie-web-1.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2015-09-19 20:25:14 EDT; 35min ago
 Main PID: 32292 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

...
... the first line are not important ... 
...
Warning: alagarderie-web-1.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

Warning, WHAT! I knew I'd hate myself when I find the problem...

Changes to a SystemD script file are not synced automatically. I reloaded my app target, then started it; et voila!

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq offers an example systemd unit file which might be helpful.  It shows how to properly set the environment with -e:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/systemd/sidekiq.service

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundler exec sidekiq -e production
```

Comment: I know... I this is the setup I tried first! No luck though, `RAILS_ENV` is still set "development".