# RAILS_ENV=production doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I put "RAILS_ENV=production" rake about doesn't shows up production info.

```
deployer@proj:/var/www/proj# RAILS_ENV=production rake about
About your application's environment
Rails version             4.2.0
Ruby version              2.2.1-p85 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version          2.4.6
Rack version              1.6.1
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
Middleware                Rack::Sendfile, Rack::Loc.......
Application root          /var/www/proj
Environment               development
Database adapter          mysql2
Database schema version   20150615041442
```

I even try:
    export RAILS_ENV=production
    RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
    bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 0):

have checked in rails console
like this....

> Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)

try this

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production' in environment.rb

```
sudo bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

sudo bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

this may help you [robmclarty.com](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-production-server-for-rails-4)

[stackoverflow.com/a/27434582/3248148](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27434582/3248148)

Comment: ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production' not working, still getting in development.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the environment using `bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production` and then run your rake tasks.