# Run 'rails server' on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I'm got a Rails 4.2.5 application and I need to run 'rails server' on production, I tried some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949229/change-a-rails-application-to-production):

```
rails server -e production

RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

But I get this error:

> missing region; use :region option or export region name to
>   ENV['AWS_REGION'] (Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError)

Am I missing some configurations?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have some S3/AWS config for your production environment (e. g. for Paperclip) that needs to be set. You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or rbenv-vars for setting ENV variables that are automatically loaded. Have a look at production.rb and see if you can find the config where this is needed.