# Ruby on Rails PG::ConnectionBad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app, when I run the command

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

I get an errr

PG::ConnectionBad

could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Extracted source (around line #56):

```
### Convenience alias for PG::Connection.new.
def self::connect( *args )
    return PG::Connection.new( *args )
end
```

my database.yml is

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

======= UPDATE =====

I now get an error that says ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError, 
FATAL: database "sale_development" does not exist

when i updated database.yml to

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sale_development
  pool: 5

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sale_test
  pool: 5

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sale_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: sale
  password: <%= ENV['SALE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

=> Booting Puma
ckout'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in`call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in`call'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in`block in spawn_thread'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompat17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:3Tasks: TOP => db:create
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompat17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:136:in`create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:2/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:3/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock./usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each'/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in`each_current_configuration'/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:136:in `create_current'/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:27:in`block (2 levels) in '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

===== UPDATE ====

Gemfile

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

 git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
   repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
 end


 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem 'pg'
 # Use Puma as the app server
 gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
 # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
 gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'


# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: just run rake db:create to create your database, and then then run rake db:migrate if you already have a model

Comment: if your server new and still do not have data and it's production server then run RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create and then continue with RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate

Comment: I tried that, but got a long list of errors

Comment: can you paste 10 lines above?

Comment: check in your Gemfile, do you have line gem 'pg' ?

Comment: I do have it, gem 'pg'

Comment: ok since it's in production server have you installed the pg gem also in the production server?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably not, gonna post my gemfile above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149244/discussion-between-widjajayd-and-bockdavidson).

Comment: Did you have Postgres app running? If you are using MAC, do yo see an elephant icon on the top right?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion it showing the connection with sqlite3, if it's production then you have to put the user name and password

this is for your reference if using postgresql

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_database_name
  pool: 5

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_database_name_test
  pool: 5

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_database_name_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: some_user_name
  password: some_password
```

Comment: the name of my file is sale, so would sale be the name of the database? Sorry if I sound dumb, but I am very new to this

Comment: we all learning here, if you know exactly your database name as sale then you can change inside production part database: sale and if the database server located in different server make sure you change host from localhost to the IP of the database

Comment: It seems like no matter what I do, I just can't get rid of the error

Comment: mark gem 'sqlite3', since you plan to use pg, make it non active

Comment: I did that, made no difference, keeps saying "sale_development" does not exist, but it should since "sale" is the name of the folder when I created it with rails new sale

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949229/change-a-rails-application-to-production this is good to read for your case